# PiP (Picture in Picture) as soon as I join in using jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk

Tags: android, ios, flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

So I was able to run jitsi on my flutter app with these feature flags.

`featureFlags: { "prejoinpage.enabled": false, "pip.enabled": true, },`

I am able to join the meet immediately which is one of the requirements. The other one was enabling PiP as soon as I join. Is there a way to change the orientation from full screen to PiP as soon as i join instead of manually doing it inside the jitsi meet?

I tried to use `pip.enabled` as the previous jitsi packages mentioned about it but on this package it seems like the feature flag only describes if pip can be enabled or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.